# grep and awk are not displaying output in terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, unix, grep, awk

When trying to `grep` Record in .txt file simply

```
$ grep 'Record' file.txt
$
```

it goes to the next line without any output or error (I've tried to write output in file, but it is empty)

I've tried also to use double quotations mark and pipe like:

```
$ grep "Record" file.txt
```

or

```
$ cat file.txt| grep "Record"
```

....still nothing. The same problem has `awk` command.

```
$ awk '{print}' file.txt
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

The relevant fragment of the output of `od -c file.txt` is:

```
0001000    ;   2   .   1  \r  \n   3   .   2   ;   1   .   8  \r  \n   3
0001020    .   2   ;   1   .   8  \r  \n   R   e   c   o   r   d       d
```

The lines in `file.txt`:

```
3.2;1.8
3.2;1.8
Record done
```

[image: lines]

BTW, before to get the `file.txt`, first I unziped `folder.zip`. This unziped folder contains csv files, and I tried to use filter like `grep` and `awk` for `file.csv` file. Since it didn't give any result, I considered to convert `file.csv` to `file.txt`.
I used the loop:

```
$ while read line; do echo $line; done <file.csv > file.txt
```

And neither `grep` nor `awk` work even for `file.txt`.

Comment: should mean that the search did not fins anything. grep is by default case sensitive, so you might try with `grep -i "smthng" file.txt` and "the same problem has awk" what do you mean , you did not present an example.

Comment: Please provide [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659). We know the `grep` commands but not the `awk` command(s) you used. And most importantly we don't know the content of your `file.txt`. You can [edit] and add information.

Comment: (1) Does `echo Record` print `Record`? (2) Does `printf '%s\n' 'Record done' | grep 'Record'` print anything? (3) How about `printf '%s' 'Record done' | grep 'Record'`?

Comment: Yes it prints out, but still not for text

Comment: What is the output of `od -c file.txt`? A fragment showing `Record` (or alleged `Record`) is enough, not necessarily the entire output.

Comment: The output of od -c file.txt is:
0001000   ;   2   .   1  \r  \n   3   .   2   ;   1   .   8  \r  \n   3
0001020   .   2   ;   1   .   8  \r  \n   R   e   c   o   r   d       d
The lines in file.txt:
3.2;1.8
3.2;1.8
Record done

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add all relevant information *there* (try to apply proper formatting). Comments are for us to ask you for more information. They are not for posting such information. The question body is for this.

Comment: BTW, before to get the file.txt, first I unziped folder.zip. This unzip folder contains csv files, and I tried to use filter like "grep" and "awk" for file.csv file . Since id didnt give any result, I considered to convert file.csv to file.txt.
I used the loop: while read line; do echo $line; done <file.csv > file.txt
And still neither grep nor awk dont work even for file.txt

Comment: I just had this as well - it seems to be a display issue with the DOS line endings (`\r\n`)? If I pipe the output to a file and look at the file in vim, I see the output, but not directly through STDOUT in the terminal. I was able to get past it by running `dos2unix` on the file.